# Why google scholar traffic is considered as Referral Traffic but not organic Traffic

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-scholar

I have tried analyzing Google Analytics Acquisition Reports for one of the websites that I work on (Publishing Platform). I see that traffic from Google Scholar here is considered as Referral Traffic. Isn't it supposed to be considered as Organic Traffic as Google Scholar is also a type of Search Engine?

Am I missing something? Or is this an exception?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not recognized as a **Google Search Domain**.

Here you can find list about default search engine list recognized ad `organic-search sources`: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

The related definition for Google is *All Google Search domains*. Here you can find list of all Google search domains: https://www.google.com/supported_domains and https://scholar.google.com/ is not in the list.